# How can I install Java from the command line only?

Tags: java, wget

When I try to download the link directly using wget I get redirected to an error page.  How can I download the official JDK from Oracle?

Answer (score 4):

A better solution is to install default java:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

This will install all of the latest packages for the default jdk product.

Comment: Where is the jdk installed. I need to set JAVA_HOME for tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want Oracle Java or is OpenJDK fine?

For example, to install OpenJDK version 1.6 of just the jre you would type

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Comment: There is also 7 no? (: